# Is there a way with CSS to center the content within an ion-content with a set width?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I want to set the width of the ion-content to 750px and then center it on the screen. Is this possible?

I've tried it by setting margin-right and margin-left to auto. I have also tried to use flex-box and justify-content and align-content. But the ion-content is just left aligned on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

To set the width of an `ion-content` element to 750px and center it on the screen in an Ionic application, you can use CSS flexbox. Here's how you can do it:

1. First, ensure you have a class or selector for your `ion-content` element. For example:

```html
<ion-content class="custom-content">
  <!-- Content goes here -->
</ion-content>
```

2. In your CSS (or SCSS) file, define the styles for the `custom-content` class:

```css
.custom-content {
  width: 750px;         /* Set the desired width */
  margin: 0 auto;       /* Center the element horizontally */
  display: flex;        /* Enable flexbox layout */
  justify-content: center; /* Center the content horizontally within the element */
  align-items: center;     /* Center the content vertically within the element */
}
```

This CSS code will set the `ion-content` element to a fixed width of 750px, center it horizontally on the screen, and center its content both horizontally and vertically within the element.

Make sure that you're not applying conflicting styles from other CSS rules that might affect the positioning of the `ion-content`. Also, be aware that the actual layout may be influenced by other components and styles in your Ionic app, so you may need to adjust your CSS accordingly.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, the ion-content is still left aligned.